# What does the complementizer "that" accomplish in terms of style?

Tags: conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

I've always refrained from using words that weren't necessary to conform with grammar rules and didn't add to the meaning of a sentence.  Being a fan of brevity, I don't use the complementizer *that* unless it is necessary for the sentence to be grammatical or it clears up an ambiguity within the sentence. But I've been told the complementizer *that* serves a stylistic purpose as well. Exactly what stylistic purpose it serves has always been a mystery to me.  Whenever I ask someone, they respond with the frustrating answer "sometimes it sounds better". So what exactly is the stylistic end the complementizer *that* accomplishes?

For instance:

> Raines said (that) this incident was "uncharacteristic of most interactions" between the U.S. and Iranian navies. CNN
>
> Col. Steve Warren said (that) 10 senior ISIS leaders operating in both Iraq and Syria, "including several external attack planners," with designs on attacking western targets, had been killed in airstrikes. CNN

If the complementizer *that* were inserted into the above sentences, how would *that* affect the way the sentence is read?

This question is related to another question I asked yesterday,
[Does using "that" to introduce a subordinate clause serve any other purpose but to eliminate ambiguity?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296490/does-using-that-to-introduce-a-subordinate-clause-serve-any-other-purpose-but)

Comment: First, you need to include the link(s) of all the questions you asked about the subject. Second, your question is close to asking for **primarily-opinion-based** answers.

Comment: Why have a style tag, if I can't ask questions about style?

Comment: Just because there is a tag **meaning** doesn't necessarily mean you can ask "What does the English word style mean?". You need to edit your post first and let other users judge it. I have not close-voted your question yet and I am giving you a piece of advice.

Comment: If there is a style tag, I can ask questions about what a certain phrasing or word usage accomplishes stylistically.   What other interpretation of the tag is there?

Comment: Now, you need to elaborate on what you don't understand from the previous question and answer and what you need to know further focusing on the difference between the two questions. Your question is close to being a duplicate of the previous question.

Comment: No it's not.  One is general, the other is specific.

Comment: Didn't you understand what I meant in the second comment? Click on the tag and you can see yourself what questions belong to the tag. Many of them have been closed and many of them were tagged mistakenly I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the piece of text is read aloud, the word *that* marks the words that follow as reported speech. Consider your examples when read aloud without *that* - the words that follow "(that)" could be reported speech or direct quotes. In terms of style, *that* helps avoid this ambiguity.

The strong link between *that* and reported speech can sometimes also help provide some emotional distance between the messenger and the message. E.g., "Tom said you should go" vs "Tom said that you should go".