# Should I use the word "that" in a sentence when it is not required?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions, subordinate-clauses, subordinators

In this sentence

> My sister told me that she didn't want pancakes for breakfast.

The sentence would still make sense even if the word "that" is taken out. How would one decide to use the word "that" in a sentence? Is it considered better writing when "that" is not used when it is not required?

Comment: [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296720/what-does-the-complementizer-that-accomplish-in-terms-of-style) may be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

As a rough rule of thumb, if the verb in the main clause is both high frequency and simple, we tend to prefer to omit *that* [except in highly formal writing]. In other circumstances we normally prefer to leave it in.

---

**Full answer**

> My sister told me that she didn't want pancakes for breakfast.

In the sentence above, the phrase *she didn't want pancakes for breakfast* is a Complement of the adjective *told*. This type of clause is known as a content clause (as opposed to a relative clause, or a comparative clause).

Content clauses are often introduced by the subordinator *that*:

- I know [that you ate my last chocolate biscuit].

We only use *that* with declarative content clauses, not interrogative ones or exclamative ones:

- *I wonder that if she is going to the party. (ungrammatical)
- *I saw that how big the elephant was! (ungrammatical)

**When to use *that* in declarative content clauses**

We always use *that* with a content clause when a content clause is the Subject of a sentence:

- [That you were late again] will not impress the powers that be.
- *[You were late again] will not impress the powers that be. (ungrammatical)

We also always use *that* if the content clause has been moved to a position before the Subject:

- [That I need help] I freely admit.

The sentence above is a version of *I freely admit that I need help*, where the Complement of admit has been moved to before the Subject, *I*.

We rarely use *that* if the content clause is the Complement of a preposition:

- I will see you after you've finished your meeting.
- *I will see you after that you have finished your meeting. (ungrammatical)

[There are a handful of very unusual prepositions such as *notwithstanding* which allow *that*.]

In nearly all other cases where the content clause is the Complement of a verb, noun, or adjective the word *that* is optional. It can be omitted or included as you see fit:

- I know that you ate my biscuits.
- I know you ate my biscuits.
- I'm happy you ate my biscuits
- I am happy that you ate my biscuits.
- The fact you ate my biscuits really gets my goat.
- The fact that you ate my biscuits really gets my goat.

We are far more likely to omit that it's the Complement of a simple high frequency verb, adjective or noun. We are also far less likely to omit *that* in formal writing:

- The notion you ate my biscuit is laughable. (slightly awkward because of *notion*)
- We therefore need to underline we going to be there. (awkward because formal and because of the long as well as low frequency verb *underline*)

**Conclusion**

In the Original Poster's sentence the content clause is the complement of the simple and high frequency verb *tell*. The context is also not formal. The Original Poster can therefore freely omit *that*. The sentence will be both grammatical and appropriate.

---

**References**

<sup>Most of this information is available in:</sup> <sup>[*A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*](http://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar) Huddleston & Pullum, 2005.</sup>